# Cannot set cookies between frontend and backend server

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, vercel, setcookie

I have my frontend to my MERN stack hosted on vercel and my backend hosted on render.
Here is my cors settings.

```
const corsConfig = {
  origin: true,
  credentials: true,
};

app.use(cors(corsConfig));
app.options('*', cors(corsConfig));
```

here is how I am setting my cookies

```
const token = jwt.sign({ _id: savedUser._id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET_TOKEN);
const domain = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? '.vercel.app' : 'localhost';
res.cookie('token', token, { domain, httpOnly: true, sameSite: 'None', secure: true });
```

Here is a screenshot of my network set-cookie error

[set-cookie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMZEb.png)

When hovering over the yellow icon I get the message "attempt to set a cookie via a set-cookie header was blocked because its domain attribute was invalid with regards to the current host url"

Any help in resolving this would be greatly appreciated. My frontend url is something like https://hi.vercel.app/ and my backend url is something like https://bye.onrender.com

I tried setting the domain, sameSite, and secure attributes but none of that worked. It works on my localhost from localhost:3000 to localhost:5001 but doesnt work when I deploy my code to production.

Comment: seems obvious that a response from `bye.onrender.com` can't set a cookie for the domain `.vercel.app` - I can't imagine why that should ever work

Comment: why is this obvious? If I can't do it like this how can I have my backend server send my frontend a jwt token?

Comment: I think you mean how can your front end request a jwt from the backend - there's a disctinction - and for a website whose url is hi.vercel.app, its backend is hi.vercel.app, any other url is a cross origin one